# Use hooks to format table in output

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Using knitr and R Markdown, I can produce a tabularised output from a matrix using the following command:

````
```{r results='asis'}
kable(head(x))
```
````

However, I’m searching for a way to make the `kable` code implicit since I don’t want to clutter the echoed code with it. Essentially, I want this:

````
```{r table=TRUE}
head(x)
```
````

… to yield a formatted tabular (rather than the normal `output='markdown'`) output.

I actually thought this must be pretty straightforward since it’s a pretty obvious requirement, but I cannot find any way to achieve this, either via the documentation or on the web.

My approach to create an output hook fails because once the data arrives at the hook, it’s *already* formatted and no longer the raw data. Even when specifying `results='asis'`, the hook obtains the output as a *character string* and not as a matrix. Here’s what I’ve tried:

```
default_output_hook <- knit_hooks$get('output')
knit_hooks$set(output = function (x, options)
    if (! is.null(options$table))
        kable(x)
    else
        default_output_hook(x, options)
)
```

But like I said, this fails since `x` is not the original matrix but rather a character string, and it doesn’t matter which value for the `results` option I specify.

Comment: It has been on the plan for quite a while, and I know how to do it but still have not find time for it yet: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/484 Eventually I'll allow users define their own printing functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think other answers are from a time when the following didn't work, but now we can just do :

````
```{r results='asis', render=pander::pander}
head(x)
```
````

Or set this for all chunks in the setup chunk, for instance :

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, render=pander::pander)
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays one can set `df_print` in the YAML header:

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: kable  
---

```{r}
head(iris)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Lacking a better solution I’m currently re-parsing the character string representation that I receive in the hook. I’m posting it here since it kind of works. However, parsing a data frame’s string representation is never perfect. I haven’t tried the following with anything but my own data and I fully expect it to break on some common use-cases.

```
reparse <- function (data, comment, ...) {
    # Remove leading comments
    data <- gsub(sprintf('(^|\n)%s ', comment), '\\1', data)
    # Read into data frame
    read.table(text = data, header = TRUE, ...)
}

default_output_hook <- knit_hooks$get('output')

knit_hooks$set(output = function (x, options)
    if (is.null(options$table))
        default_output_hook(x, options)
    else {
        extra_opts <- if (is.list(options$table)) options$table else list()
        paste(kable(do.call(reparse, c(x, options$comment, extra_opts))),
              collapse = '\n')
    }
)
```

This **will** break if the R markdown `comment` option is set to a character sequence containing a regular expression special char (e.g. `*`), because R doesn’t seem to have an obvious means of escaping a regular expression.

Here’s a usage example:

````
```{r table=TRUE}
data.frame(A=1:3, B=4:6)
```
````

You can pass extra arguments to the `deparse` function. This is necessary e.g. when the table contains `NA` values because `read.table` by default interprets them as strings:

````
```{r table=list(colClasses=c('numeric', 'numeric'))}
data.frame(A=c(1, 2, NA, 3), B=c(4:6, NA))
```
````

Far from perfect, but at least it works (for many cases).

Comment: This fails for wide matrices since their rows are broken up into multiple lines. Sigh.

Comment: That is hackish. There will be a more natural way to do it hopefully in December. I'm busy with other things at the moment.

Comment: @Yihui Great news, thanks. “This is hackish” – that should be clear as soon as you read “re-parsing”. ;-)

Comment: Yes. My goal is to remove the prefix "re" in re-parsing :)

Comment: This is late, but might be helpful. I got around this with `evaluate()` applied to the `knit_hooks$set()` source and then Kable code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52529973/8675075).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but I am posting an answer here (that could not fit in a comment) as your described workflow is really similar to what my initial goal and use-case was when I started to work on my `pander` package. Although I really like the bunch of chunk options that are available in `knitr`, I wanted to have an engine that makes creating documents really easy, automatic and without any needed tweaks. I am aware of the fact that `knitr` hooks are really powerful, but I just wanted to set a few things in my `Rprofile` and let the literate programming tool its job without further trouble, that ended to be [`Pandoc.brew`](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc) for me.

The main idea is to specify a few options (what markdown flavour are you using, what's your decimal mark, favorite colors for your charts etc), then simply write your report in a brew syntax without any chunk options, and **the results of your code would be automatically transformed to markdown**. Then convert that to pdf/docx/odt etc. with Pandoc.