# Using R-markdown knitr hooks to custom format tables in HTML reports

Tags: r, hook, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to set up a `knitr::knit_hooks()` to automatically format data frame output of an R-markdown chunk with `kableExtra` in my HTML report.

I would like to not repeatedly add the following lines (or any lines) to the end of each chunk of tabulated data:

```
head(iris) %>%
  kable("html") %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = FALSE)
```

I came up with one solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19880010/8675075) that works by evaluating the chunk *source* (see my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52529973/8675075) that includes some issues that I have with this approach); I'm hoping there might be a better solution using the chunk *output*.

Here is an example .Rmd with an outline of what I would like to achieve.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Paul"
date: "25 September 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = F}

library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

data(iris)

default_source_hook <- knit_hooks$get('source')

knit_hooks$set(
  output = function(x, options) {
    x %>%
      kable("html") %>%
      kable_styling("hover", full_width = FALSE)
  },
  source = function(x, options) {
    if(is.null(options$table))
      default_source_hook(x, options)
    else {
      eval(parse(text = x)) %>%
        kable("html") %>%
        kable_styling("hover", full_width = F)
    }}
)


```

Desired chunk input:

```{r test, echo = F}
head(iris)

```

Desired output will look like:

```{r output, echo = F}
head(iris) %>%
  kable("html") %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = FALSE)

```

Solution using the source chunk output:

```{r table_format, results = "hide", table = T, eval = F}
head(iris)

```
````

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If using knit hooks is not necessary, the following might help. The idea is to just define a function that prints whatever it gets exactly the way you want. This does not eliminate all typing, but reduces it substantially.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Paul"
date: "25 September 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = F}

library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

tbl_out <- function(data) {
  data %>% kable("html") %>% kable_styling("hover", full_width = FALSE)
}
```

Prints as desired:

```{r test, echo = F}
head(iris) %>% tbl_out()
```
````

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found a work-around by using the `knit_hooks()` **source** as the formatted chunk output.

The difficulty in formatting the chunk **output** is that character data is passed to the hook. Drawing inspiration from the linked answer in the OP, I found a solution by evaluating the chunk **source** in `knit_hooks()`.

This solution re-evaluates the chunk and is piped into the desired `KableExtra` formatting.

I needed to add a new chunk option `table = T` so that the formatting was only applied to source code that produces a data table; `results = "hide"` was also needed so the default chunk output was not included in the report.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Paul"
date: "27 September 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = F}

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

default_source_hook <- knit_hooks$get('source')

knit_hooks$set(
  source = function(x, options) {
    if(is.null(options$table))
      default_source_hook(x, options)
    else {
      eval(parse(text = x)) %>%
        kable("html") %>%
        kable_styling("hover", full_width = F)
    }

  }
)

data(iris)

```

## Normal
With no chunk options:

```{r normal}
head(iris)

```

## The desired ouptut
With chunk options `results = "hide"` and `table = T`:

```{r table_format, results = "hide", table = T, eval = F}
head(iris)

```

## It still work as normal for other other output types
With no chunk options:

```{r image}
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species)) +
  geom_point()

```
````

There are a few problems with this solution

1. the code used to produce the table is now unavailable
2. eval = F should be included - especially if the code will take a while to run (as it is again evaluated in the hook)
3. I'm replacing 2 lines of code with 3 chunk options - although not a deal killer it's not quite as automagical as I would have liked.