# rmarkdown kable - set up kable_styling to be used repetitively

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, kable, kableextra

I am wondering if there is a way to set up a `kable_styling` that I can use throughout my `rmarkdown`/`bookdown` kind like you would set up a `ggplot` theme. Here is a small example where you just set the table to striped:

```
kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:5]) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", fixed_thead = T)
```

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877286/use-hooks-to-format-table-in-output) and/or the two other linked ones. Hard to say for certain without a reproducible example, but those seem like they should help.

Comment: That does look like setting up a ggplot theme? I mean... you still have to call your theme function with it's options.

Comment: you can set a theme and then call it later for example: `newtheme <- theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "darkred"))` then you can call it again with `ggplot(...) + newtheme` this would save a lot of copy pasting.